# How do I use stripe cli as a docker service?

Tags: docker, stripe-payments

Thanks in advance for all your support guys!!!!

So, I have a dockerized django application in which I want to maintain the stripe-cli webhook command:

```
stripe listen --foward-to http://host-name:8000/webhook/...
```

by having it(stripe-cli) as a docker service and what I have done to try to make it work is as shown below:

```
services:
   stripe-cli:
    image: stripe/stripe-cli
    container_name: stripe-cli
    command: "listen --api-key=my_stripe_login_key --forward-to http://localhost:8000/stripe/webhook"
```

But when I try to build the docker compose file, I am getting an error;

```
stripe-cli  | exec /bin/stripe: exec format error
stripe-cli exited with code 1
```

I will appreciate for any of your feedback!

Other Information:

I have an ubuntu docker base image

I am using an arc-based linux distribution **XeroLinux** on my host machine

Answer (score 0):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-cli/issues/993) with the Stripe CLI and the latest version of the Docker container.  If you specify the container version as `v1.12.4` you should be able to run your docker service following the guidance for the CLI [here](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-cli#docker).

I would watch the issue to get updated when the issue gets resolved.  Also you can bump the issue by commenting on it.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using image for wrong architecture.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34747717)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).